# Tastypie: turn Django 500 "Unknown MySQL server host" into 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: django, tastypie

Whenever there's a problem connecting between my application server and my database server, it throws a 500 "Unknown MySQL server host" error. I have these problems well-characterized and would like to change the 500 to a 502 Bad Gateway error. The stack trace for the 500 doesn't pass through any of my own code of course. What's the cleanest place to catch and recharacterize this server-connection error?

Answer (score 1):

[django middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/)

you wrap all view in django application and catch db exception

```
class DbExceptCatcherMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        def catcher(view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
            def f(view_args, view_kwargs):
                try:
                   return view_func(*view_args, **view_kwargs)
                except DatabaseError:
                   raise HttpResponse(content='Unknown MySQL server host', status=502)
            return f
        view_func = catcher(view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
```

in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

'path.to.module.DbExceptCatcherMiddleware',
)
```

this may help, but i'm not sure on. i not test this code.

Or you can use decorators

```
def wrapp_excep(func):
    def f(*arg, **kwd):
        try:
           return func(*arg, **kwd)
        except DatabaseError:
           raise HttpResponse(content='Unknown MySQL server host', status=502)
    return f

@wrapp_excep
def your_view_1(request):
    ....

@wrapp_excep
def your_view_2(request):
    ....
```

Comment: This looks like great advice and probably answers the question as I asked it (whence my upvote!); I've since clarified that my app is a tastypie API rather than django views. I tried applying the middleware solution using process_response instead of process_view, and had no luck (process_response did not fire).